# How can I download files from my gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-io

I was able to create a GridView that displays the files and date modified but now I need to allow my users to download them. Here is what I have tried:

**Code in my FormLoad**

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(strDirectory));
List<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles().ToList();
GridView1.DataSource = files;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Download File Method**

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
    filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
```

**Linkbutton in GridView**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" 
    Text = "Download" <%-----CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>'-----%>
    runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I had to comment the command argument out because when I changed the code in the formload from this in order to get the date/time modified:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(strDirectory));
List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
}
GridView1.DataSource = files;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

it started giving the error ***DataBinding: 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'.*** How do I fix this?

Comment: what is this `Response.ContentType = ContentType;` shouldn't you define the Response.ContentType as "text/csv" or something for example..

Comment: Huge security risk in DownloadFile - it lets anyone download any file from your server machine (path can be changed by users afaik)

Comment: I  also see that you are not calling `Response.Flush()` before `Response.End()`

Comment: @cDima the path is predefined, and only users with access to the server via custom login(AD will have access to it)

Comment: I see what hes doing, @ObadiahWilliams your issue is comming from the renamed variable in your form load. when the page loads filePath is no longer present. But usually it would not matter because the variables in the download method is outside of the scope of the formload.

Comment: @Skullomania thats exactly where i am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, `FileInfo` doesn't have a property called `Value`.  [It has other properties, though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

Based on your `DownloadFile` method implementation it looks like you expect that value to be the file system path.  That would be the `FullName` property.  So it might look like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" 
Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("FullName") %>'
runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Be aware that this isn't a great idea, though.  It's giving file system information to your users.  By itself that might not seem so bad, but if a malicious user is attempting to gather information about your server then you're just providing him with another piece of information.  Ultimately, users of your application don't need to know about your server-side file system, so you shouldn't tell them about it.

I would recommend maintaining some kind of identifier for your files.  If they're all in the same directory then you can simply use the name of the file:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" 
Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Name") %>'
runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And then you'd need to create the full path server-side:

```
string fileName = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
string filePath = Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName);
```

(`directoryName` would be the path to the directory containing the files, however you'd like to determine that.  A `Web.config` value works pretty well for that.)

If they're not in the same folder then I would recommend using a database table to track files.  All that table really needs is a primary key (an `IDENTITY` columns works well for that) and the path for the file.

Then you would bind to that database table, not to the collection of files.  The `CommandArgument` would be the identifier for the table records, and the `DownloadFile` implementation would use the identifier to look up the table record, then use the file path form that record to get the file.